# How can I wait on multiple results, then filter them based on received data?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx

I have two observables that I would like to wait for the results of both so I can filter the results of one based upon the other. Individually they wor:

```
this.allValues$ = this.store.select(selectors.getAllValues)
this.myId$ = this.store.select(selectors.myId)
```

and I can render them to the template with the async pipe

However I would like to make a class property which holds a filtered array. If it were synchronous JS, something like

```
this.filteredResults = allValues.filter(value => value.id === myId)
```

`zip`ing will get me the values

```
this.filteredResults$ = zip(
  this.store.select(selectors.getAllValues),
  this.store.select(selectors.myId)
)
```

template:
    results: {{ filteredResults$ | async | json }}

But I cannot understand how to filter like I want. I've tried chaining a `pipe` to the `zip`:

```
.pipe(
   tap((...args) => {
     console.log({ args }) // only one result so no hope of dropping in `map` or `filter` here
   })
)
```

But this has the effect of removing the `allValues` array from the result set. `allValues` is vastly larger so presumably taking longer and zip is no longer waiting for everything to emit so I guess `pipe` isn't the solution, though it seems close.

#### How can I can I access both these result sets, filter them, and put that result in an observable I can render in the template with `filteredResults$ | async | json`?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `concatMap` or `switchMap`.

```
this.filteredResults = this.store.select(selectors.myId).pipe(
  concatMap(myId => {
    return this.store
      .select(selectors.getAllValues)
      .pipe(filter(value => value.id === myId));
  })
);
```

Comment: I don’t see here how to use the `myId` given by the one observable in the filtering of the array observable. Here ks looks like `myId` is a synchronously declared constant.

Comment: aha, I see what you need, gimme a sec

Comment: Why do you suggest `switchMap`? Wouldn’t that unsubscribe from the first observable when the second emits? If `selectors.myId` changes will that subscription re-start?

Comment: @1252748, I said `or` , obviously they're different, but I don't know your entire business logic. I'm not hired by the company that you're working for. I just gave you the correct logic, you should adopt it.

Comment: Oh god. You people always make me laugh.

Answer (score -1):

It's easy to overlook `NgRx` selectors. You should check out the documentation, because what you are trying to achieve is possible with the `createSelector` method. This will have multiple benefits (cleaner code, reusable selector, etc)

https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#using-selectors-for-multiple-pieces-of-state

Something like this might work in your case:

```
export const yourCombinedSelector = createSelector(
  selectors.getAllValues,
  selectors.myId,
  (allValues, myId) => {
    // perform logic and return the data you need
  }
);
```

Then

```
const data$ = this.store.select(selectors.yourCombinedSelector)
```

Comment: I like this idea, however it seems since the data is being returned asynchronously the value selected by `selectors.getAllValues` is null in the third function passed to `createSelector`.